# Change Login Form:Username to Select Text

Tags: users, forms

Is it possible to change the login form? Specifically the Textbox for username to select text?

Let's say I have 4 users named: User1,User2,User3,User4 and when select text is clicked. All users will be listed as a choice?

PS: I'm very new to drupal detailed help will be appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion the answer to your question is extremely complicated, involving the default user login process and the drupal 7 form api. Are you sure you need that exact approach? You can't say use a select box made from Views and use Rules to login the given user's `user_id` once selected? I mean, why do you want to change the real `user_login` form to show a select list of specific users ...

Comment: Can you give me more details about what do you mean about using views and rules? Or examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can do it using function **hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)** {}

Just include this function in **template.php** of your theme or in you module.

If you theme name is "testtheme" then replace **hook** with you theme name(**testtheme**).

OR 
you can include it in your custom module. If you have custom module with name "testmod"  then just add this code in your module and replace the **hook** with your module name (**testmod**)

```
function **hook**_custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){

    //Get the users  from database or keep it static according to requirement
    $users  =   array("user1"=>"User 1","user2"=>"User 2","user3"=>"User 3");
    if($form_id=="user_login"){
    $form['name']['#type'] = "select";
    $form['name']['#options'] = $users;
    $form['name']['#required'] = true;
   $form['name']['#size']='auto';

    }


    }
```

Don't forget to clear drupal cache.
Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved my life. But one more thing, and this might be very obvious. It shows up like this. http://i62.tinypic.com/25iptat.png

Comment: I have updated my code for this issue using #size. Please check